# Is there something similar to #define in C/C++ for a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, root-framework

I am currently working on a script which calls a few programs, e.g.:

```
root -l -q Analysis.C+'("var1", "var2", "var3")'
```

I now want a bash script that automatically replaces the user input with var1, var2, var3, etc. However, if I write something like

```
root -l -q Analysis.C+'("$1", "$2", "$3")'
```

this does not seem to work, as it intrprets $1 and so an as strings and not as variables. Is there something similar to #define like in C/C++ where the variable is  replaced in the whole script before running? Or how can this be done?

Comment: Eh? `root -l -q Analysis.C+'("var1", "var2", "var3");` isn't a valid command -- it starts a single-quoted string but never ends it.

Comment: Is that unpaired single quote part of the command? How do you want the final text to appear? You should be able to use `$1` etc, but the syntax will be critical. Show your desired shell command you are trying to create. In other words, are you hoping to run that command 3x, with 1,2,3 in succession or are those all parts of the same single command?

Comment: what happens with your example when you run it as `set -- one two three ; echo root -l -q 'Analysis.C+'("$1", "$2", "$3");` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, well, it would emit `> ` and hang, waiting for the single-quoted context to be closed.

Comment: yep, I have corrected my sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot perform preprocessing regardless of quoting context. This is because **the very point** of quoting contexts in shell is to control which kind of substitutions do and don't take place. If you could define substitutions that happened in single quotes, the meaning that single-quotes have in shell (that characters within them as treated as literal and not subject to expansions) would be lost.

---

Doing this right would look something like:

```
root -l -q Analysis.C+'("'"$var1"'", "'"$var2"'", "'"$var3"'");'
```

That is to say: The single-quoted context is ended, and a double-quoted context is started, before each parameter substitution.

---

The effect of this can be seen below:

```
$ var1=a; var2=b; var3=c
$ printf '%s\n' root -l -q Analysis.C+'("'"$var1"'", "'"$var2"'", "'"$var3"'");'
root
-l
-q
Analysis.C+("a", "b", "c");
```